# HD4400 dual monitor mini displayport

Tags: intel-graphics

How can I get ubuntu 12.04 (or later) to recognise a second monitor on a gigabyte brix with intel hd4400. The HDMI works fine the mini display port is not recognised, was hoping intel drivers would fix it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, was of help have narrowed it down to its the drivers. The second display is not detected at all which makes me think the mini display port isn't registering. I am guessing the hardware may be too new to fully be used as yet, though the functionality is apparently available through Win 7. Will have to wait til the Intel drivers for 13.10 are released via Intel PPA. Or the kernel adds that function maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a second monitor before. First, you need to know the resolution of the monitor (just google it if you don't know.) Then, go into the System Settings, and into the Displays tab. I'm guessing that you want the screens to extend on eachother, so you can uncheck the box that is labeled "Mirror Displays." Try pressing "Detect Displays." If your second monitor shows up, then click on it, and set the resolution. Hit apply. If that doesn't work, then (this is what I did), change the resolution of your second screen to something lower than what it actually is. Then hit apply. That's when my second screen turned on. Then, you can change the resolution to the actual resolution of the screen, and apply that. It worked for me. I don't know if I exactly answered your question or not. If the second display does not show up at all, then check all your connections. Make sure it has power, and is connected via HDMI. If it still isn't recognized, then you may want to look into getting new drivers. Though I wouldn't expect drivers to be your problem, they very well could be. If none of the things I said above worked for you, then you need to ask someone else :)

Hope that helped!
--Michael

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with either the Intel Driver or the BIOS, not the display set-up. I have several of these BRIX BXi5-4200 units. . They will boot with one monitor plugged in, but will not boot with two monitors plugged in. Video goes on, but hangs. So, after shutdown, the second monitor Best attached to the mini DP, is unplugged at an adaptor. System boots, then we plug in second monitor. No issues once the system boots. Since all monitors are live even when turned off, (but not unplugged), simply turning monitor two off doesn't help.

Since they draw such little power, at first we just left it all on, but even when all settings are set to NOT sleep, hibernate, etc. (set to always on), after 6-8 hrs the video will turn off, and won't come back up until restart.

What a disappointment.